# Generate Django SHA1 passwords

Tags: django, django-admin, passwords

I need to provide access to a Django database from another python software based on the users already created in Django. I'm ok with the whole access thing, I just need a piece of code to generate a Django password as the admin auth module does.

What would be the best way of doing that? Note that, if possible, I don't want to have the whole Django package for that.

Many Thanks

Comment: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it how it works.  I wrote a small function to check a user's password:

```
def check_passwd (user, raw_password):
     import hashlib
     # ... get 'hsh_passwd' from database based on 'user' ...
     hsh_passwd = hsh_passwd.split('$')
     salt = hsh_passwd[1]
     hsh = hsh_passwd[2]
     if hsh == hashlib.sha1(salt + raw_password).hexdigest():
         return True
     return False
```

Of course, there's not a lot of verifications and it's not flexible, but it's what I've been looking for.

Comment: `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`

Answer (score 4):

The entire code for creating and verifying user passwords is in [`django.contrib.auth.models`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/models.py).

Specifically, look at the methods [`User.set_password`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L250) and [`User.check_password`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L260). You'd need to extract those two bits and the Django code they reference to create and verify the project's user passwords as per Django.

Comment: Thanks. Got what I needed from your answer.